# As I run my test_cases paralleled with package <multiprocessing>,it throw ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, unit-testing, multiprocessing

testrun.py(I make suite all the test cases together to run them paralleled  )
snippet
....

```
    @staticmethod
    def runcase(suite,processdir):
    processlist = []
    now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
    test_result = 'C:/Users/huanri/Documents/apa_auto/test_report/' + now 
                  +'_test_result.html'

    fp = file(test_result, 'a')

    print fp.closed
    for i in suite:
        # runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
        t = 0
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream = fp,
        title = u'APA_Test_Report',
        description = u'Test Case Excution Report'
        )
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = runner.run, args = (i,))
        # print proc
        processlist.append(proc)
        t = t+1
        # print processlist
    for i in processlist:
        i.start()
    for i in processlist:
        i.join(6) 
    fp.close()
```

....

after executed testrun.py then it throw below

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
      self.run()
     File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 88, in run
      self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLTestRunner.py", line 630, in run
      self.generateReport(test, result)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLTestRunner.py", line 687, in generateReport
      self.stream.write(output.encode('utf8')) 
     ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

who can point when I close the file?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the question? If `fp.close()` is inside the `for` loop, then it may be that because it is called at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Or, most likely, your `runner` closes `fp` when it's done, so when a process finishes the file is closed and the rest processes throw that error.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to open and close file within your threads. When you start a non blocking thread the procedural code moves to the next line and calls `fp.close()`.  So you will see this exception. you can work around this by opening and closing the file within each `runner.run` .

here is some example code to see how it works. https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1234639

hope this helps